# What does '/ operator do in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am working on converting a MATLAB program to C and I don't know MATLAB at all.

I am trying to figure out this line of code:

```
var1=acos(v1true*varW1'/(norm(v1true)));
```

I know what ./ does, it causes MATLAB to divide term by term. But I don't know about '/. Can anyone tell me what '/  does in MATLAB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Brandon said, ' is the conjugate or Hermitian transpose (also known as linear algebraic transpose), and .' is the array transpose. For more information see [MATLAB's Arithmetic Operators page](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html).

Comment: Great thanks for the link. You'd have thought I could have found that with my googling... :)

Answer (score 1):

' is the conjugate or Hermitian transpose. If you wish to do a normal transpose, use .'

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in your case you are taking transpose of varW1 dividing it with the norm(v1true) then multiplying it with v1true.